# How to indicate letters conjoined across words?

Tags: arc, poetry

I'm trying to indicate how verses in Latin are scanned. Part of that is indicating where the breaks between syllables occur. Sometimes a syllable begins with a consonant at the end of one word and contains the vowel at the start of the next word. Here is a traditional way of indicating that:*

[image]

How can I get LaTeX to generate the little curve from one letter to the next, as in the example above, which shows n–e and s–e each straddling two words?

---

* <sub>From *Lingua Latina Per Se Illustrata* by Hans Ørberg, p. 292. Domus Latina, 2003.</sub>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a standard Unicode character tie:  ⁀ Unicode: U+2040.

Used with an appropriate font and XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX you can just put it directly into your source or make a macro. (Since it's designed to go on top of two characters, you need to wrap it in spaces for this use, so I've turned it into a macro:

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Junicode.ttf}
\newcommand{\tie}{~⁀~}
\begin{document}
Nōn egō nōbilium sedeō studiōsus equōrum

nō-n\tie e-gō- nō-bi-li-um- se-de-ō- stu-di-ō-su-s\tie e-quō-rum
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: What about possible line breaks? With `~⁀~` you avoid them.

Comment: This has been working wonderfully for me. I see also that U+203F is the [undertie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undertie), which I think is used to indicate‿elision on [hexameter.co](http://hexameter.co).

Answer (score 8):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

n\=o-n\t{e}\,go

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using a rotated, stretched and compressed, sans-serif "C" as the tie...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\tie{\kern-3pt%
  \smash{\rotatebox[origin=top]{-90}{\sffamily\scalebox{.8}[1.1]{~C}}}%
  \kern-3pt}
\begin{document}
Nōn egō nōbilium sedeō studiōsus equōrum

nō-n\tie e-gō- nō-bi-li-um- se-de-ō- stu-di-ō-su-s\tie e-quō-rum 
\end{document}
```

[image]